# Calling write! is outputting string wrapped in Ok() in rust

Tags: rust, output

When trying to read a file and write it to another file, each line is getting wrapped inside of Ok() when using write!. I have been unable to discover what I am doing wrong, hopefully someone will have an idea.

I have been able to isolate the issue to something having to do with the {:#?}.

If I put regulat text in the "" it prints fine and outside the Ok(). Has anyone else come across this?

Thanks

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead};
use std::io::{Write, Error};

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {

    let ofile = File::open("test.xml")?;
    let mut new_file = File::create("output.xml")?;
    let input = BufReader::new(ofile);

    for line in input.lines() {
        write!(new_file, "{:#?}", line)?;
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Input

```xml
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<Configuration xmlns="configuration" configType="TEST_RULE" actionType="NEW RULE">
   <Reference>
      <Code>AV</Code>
      <Name>TESTER</Name>
   </Reference>
   <ConfigItems>
      <ConfigItem>
         <description>Test Description</description>
      </ConfigItem>
   </ConfigItems>
</Configuration>
```

Resultant output

```
Ok(
    "<?xml version = \'1.0\' encoding = \'UTF-8\'?>"
)Ok(
    "<Configuration xmlns=\"configuration\" configType=\"TEST_RULE\" actionType=\"NEW RULE\">"
)Ok(
    "   <Reference>"
)Ok(
    "      <Code>AV</Code>"
)Ok(
    "      <Name>TESTER</Name>"
)Ok(
    "   </Reference>"
)Ok(
    "   <ConfigItems>"
)Ok(
    "      <ConfigItem>"
)Ok(
    "         <description>Test Description</description>"
)Ok(
    "      </ConfigItem>"
)Ok(
    "   </ConfigItems>"
)Ok(
    "</Configuration>"
)
```

Fix:
As per the response below, I changed the write! to the following and it fixed the issue.

```rust
write!(new_file, "{}\n", line?)?;
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `"{:#?}"` is for debug output. So, if `line` is wrapped in `Ok(...)`, it'll be printed like in your post. You should unwrap the line to get the actual string.

Comment: What made you think think that you need `write` macro for this?

Comment: Peter Varo - I was expanding on an example on the rust cookbook https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/file/read-write.html

Comment: ForceBru - Aha...that seemed to have fixed the trick. Couldn't find anything on using it only as a debugging feature...definitely good to know. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Calling `.lines()` on a `BufReader` gives you an [`io::Lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Lines.html), whose associated `Item`-type is `std::io::Result<String>`. That is, while iterating over `.lines()`, the iterator yields either an `Ok(String)` (in case the read succeeded) or an `Err(io::Error)` (in case an io-error occured while reading the next line). That is why you see `Ok(...)` being printed.

It's common to see something like the following:

```
for line in input.lines() {
    // If `line` is `Ok(String)`, re-assign `line`; return the error otherwise.
    let line = line?;
    // Possible read-errors have been dealt with, `line` is a `String`.
    write!(new_file, "{:#?}", line)?;
}
```

In case you are confused about the type of something, it is also common practice to assign to a variable of either your expected or some "absurd" type, just to get the compiler to yell at you.

```
for line in input.lines() {
    let line: String = line; // line should be a String, right?
    let line: () = line; // I have no idea what line is, but it's not () for sure 
    write!(new_file, "{:#?}", line)?;
}
```

Both `let line: ... = line` will cause the compiler to raise an error because `line` is `Result<String>` and can't be assigned to a variable that is fixed to some other type; now you know that `line` is actually `Result<String>` and not `String` as expected.